# How to change the border colour of a card upon tapping it wrapped in listview.builder in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, setstate

I am fetching certain details from firebase and showing them in the form of card, with the help of ListView.Builder. Now, upon tapping a specific card I want to change its border colour to green. I have tried using the flag variable in the setState but it sets the border colour for every card to green. Someone pls have a look at the code I've pasted, and let me know what should be done.[This is the image of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X9eI.png)

Thank You:)

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: collectionTests.snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text("Something went wrong");
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            final myDocs = snapshot.data!.docs;
            try {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: myDocs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(17, 11, 17, 11),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          side: const BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: ListTile(
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          title: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                myDocs[index]['name'],
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 22,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Card(
                                color: Colors.indigo,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    myDocs[index]['price'],
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          subtitle: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 12, 8),
                            child: Text(
                              myDocs[index]['description'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } catch (e) {
              return const Center(
                child: Card(
                  child: Text(
                    'Something went wrong, please check your connection',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          }
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract your widget into a new stateful class and call the class inside the ListView.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stackoverflow/custom_card.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, i){
            return CustomCard();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

custom_card.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomCardState createState() => _CustomCardState();
}

class _CustomCardState extends State<CustomCard> {

  Color borderColor = Colors.black;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 100,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          setState(() {
            borderColor = Colors.green;
          });
        },
        child: Card(
          color: borderColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Pls provide me the code snippet in accordance to your answer

Comment: Done. I added the code snippet.

Comment: Your code just converts all card border colors to the same color. You need to work with the index of specific card.

Comment: No, i tested the code and it actually changes the individual card's color when I click them.

Comment: I now got what you mean, yes it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the support ,but it doesn't help as the border colour for all the cards gets changed to green upon tapping any of the card. Pls provide another approach

Comment: It should work to the border color too. Can you provide the code you tried using this approach.

Comment: yeah sure, I would love to, but I am unable to post it in the comment section

Comment: You can edit your question and add new code as PS

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to define a list that contains bool variables out of build method. These variables will decide whether the border of relevant card is white or green.

```
List<bool> bordersColors = [];
```

Then in your listview like this;

```
return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: myDocs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  bordersColors.add(false);
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(17, 11, 17, 11),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                          setState((){
                               bordersColors[index] = true;
                           })
                        },
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          side: const BorderSide(
                            color: bordersColors[index] ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: ListTile(
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          title: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                myDocs[index]['name'],
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 22,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Card(
                                color: Colors.indigo,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    myDocs[index]['price'],
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          subtitle: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 12, 8),
                            child: Text(
                              myDocs[index]['description'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } catch (e) {
              return const Center(
                child: Card(
                  child: Text(
                    'Something went wrong, please check your connection',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

Comment: Thanks for the support, but it is not working properly. Upon selecting multiple cards , the border color for each card changes to green

Comment: can you pls provide another approach to it

Comment: if you still couldn't make it work, Could you please paste your whole code in the screen here; https://paste.ofcode.org/ and give me the link

Comment: Thanks fir support man, really appreciate it, but I found an alternate way